# Nginx redirect to endless var/www?

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

I am having some problems setting up my nginx server with ssl certificate and I have somehow screwed up something. When I go to my website it redirects to an endless loop of /var/wwww. it looks like this:
[image]

And this is my cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file

```html
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name molle.ws www.molle.ws;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/molle.ws/fullchain.pem; # managed by Cert$
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/molle.ws/privkey.pem; # managed by Ce$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot



    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

Please help :/

Comment: I do not see any errors in accessing your site. Can you try a different browser or clear your cache and try again? Maybe Shift + F5?

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Works just fine for me too

Comment: I'm sorry guys. My bad. My browser just got stuck up, it wouldn't clear the cache. But thank you for your response <3